# Adding *.resx files to VS Publish ->

Tags: visual-studio, msdeploy

We need to manually include our *.resx files into our Publish process. They are not normally included.
This used to work fine by adding this to the Debug.pubxml file:

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectResxFiles">
    <Message Text="=== CustomCollectResxFiles ===" Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="**\*.resx" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectResxFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectResxFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But recently it fails on my PC with the following message (It still works for my coworkers):

```
3>Skip copying C:\Users\Source\Workspaces\Supertext\Supertext\SupertextMvcSQL\obj\Debug\ApplicationInsights.config to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\ApplicationInsights.config, File obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\ApplicationInsights.config is up to date
3>Copying **\*.resx to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\**\*.resx.
3>Create Folder obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\** failed. Illegal characters in path.
3>
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 6 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've no clue where the `Illegal characters in path` are coming from. I also refreshed the entire project from TFS. So there should be no weird files lingering around.

Update:
Yes, I've tried it with Build output on Detail level. Nothing more to see.

Comment: I suspect it may be failing because of very long path. Can you copy your project to some shorter path and try again?

Comment: The problem is the `**\*` in both the source and destination, which is caused by your entry in the Debug.pubxml file. The * character is a wildcard on the Windows OS, and isn't valid for any other use. Clearly **\\* (two wildcards,  a backslash, and another wildcard) are not valid for use in either a pathname or filename. It didn't "used to work" for you at any point using that file specification.

Comment: ken-white: Thanks for the input: But I do think **\* should work. This is how it's explained in all examples I could find: E.g. https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files   
deepak-bhatia: worth a try. But since it worked until recently...